# Can't create an instance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, console-application

I have a console application and a web application.the web application call the console application and the console application create an instance of a MSWORD .it is working fine in visual studio.But when  I host the web app in IIS and try localhost:222 it don't work.
here is my code

web app code

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim info = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    info.FileName="F:\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe"
    info.Arguments = TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text
    info.UseShellExecute = True

    Dim process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    process.StartInfo = info

    process.Start()
    process.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

And the console app code is

```
Public Sub Main(args As String())
    ' CREATE AN OBJECT FOR WORD
    Dim objWord As Object
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.visible = True
End Sub
```

Anybody know what is the problem.

Comment: You should use some error handling code to catch errors and log them, but it looks like your web application doesn't have read/execute permissions on "F:\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe".
By the way, you should dispose the Word COM object after using it..

Comment: There is no error.I tried to writ the log in to a txt file when running locally the txt file having some data ,but when it is on iis it have no data ...How can we add permission ?

Comment: I guess you're using IIS7. See this: http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/

Comment: You may have moved the code out to a separate program, but you're still effectively trying to automate Word within the context of a service application - which isn't supported.